# Query to obtain TOP 3 rows across 12 months

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am currently using `MySQL` as my database.
I want to retrieve the `TOP 3` most TOPICS with the MOST POST `COUNT` for all `12 months.`
So, my result would generally give me `36 rows`. *(TOP 3 of Jan, TOP of Feb...etc.)*

**post table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Post` (
  `post_id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `staff_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `status_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `post_title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `post_date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  `latest_update` DATETIME NULL,
  `approval` INT NULL,
  `approval_date` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  INDEX `fk_Post_Staff(User)1_idx` (`staff_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Post_Topic1_idx` (`topic_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Post_Status1_idx` (`status_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Post_Staff(User)1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`staff_id`)
    REFERENCES `staff` (`staff_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Post_Topic1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`)
    REFERENCES `Topic` (`topic_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Post_Status1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`)
    REFERENCES `Status` (`status_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select floor(period/100) `year`, period%100 `month`, topic_id 
   from 
     (select @n := if(@m=period, @n:=@n+1, @n:=1) n, @m:=period period, topic_id
        from 
          (select year(post_date_time)*100+month(post_date_time) period,
                  topic_id, count(post_id) count 
             from post 
           group by period, topic_id 
           order by period, count desc) t1, 
          (select @n:=1) tn, 
          (select @m:=0) tm ) t2 
   where n<4
```

[**Demo for simplified data**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce6e7/1)

You can set the period of data by writting as the tail, for example

```
having `year` = 2015 and `month` between 1 and 6
```